# Converting two systems running in one loop to simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a MATLAB code that is running under a single for loop. In that for loop, there are two systems. Second system uses as input the outputs of first system. Now I am trying to configure it in Simulink. I created a Simulink model and in that model, there are two subsystems that I mentioned above. How can I transfer these outputs for each iteration?

I tried directly transfer the outputs of first system to second system but it only transfers the final values. I need each values of those variables for each iteration